# what is the default value for Jaspersoft to ireport in dropdowns?

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports

I have prepared a report in iReport, in which I am typing my values into my parameters.  It is successful every time.  When I have each parameter's default value to "" which essentially means that it will be empty.

Now when I put it into clarity, I have a drop down that populates with a query.  when null, it shows ---.  This is not matching the "" which is resulting in me having a blank project.  I also tried changing the code too accept ---, however that was unsuccessful.

`inner join NIKU.srm_resources on srm_resources.ID = prteam.prresourceid 
                AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),srm_resources.ID) = $P{paramResource} OR '' = $P{paramResource})`

[image]

if I **do** add a correct parameter (not leaving it null) then the report works fine.. Like i said, its just the null value that is giving me an error.

I guess my main question would be: *What do these 3 dashes check against in the sql code rather than ''?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that exactly the visible text out of the drop down is sent to the report isn't right.

**Presentation layer (JasperReport Server)**

The Server checks that the parameter isn't mandatory. It provides this record with three dashes for the user to be able to select empty / null.

If the user selects the three dashes, JasperReport Server will send `null` to the report.

If the user selects any other value, JasperReports will send the value defined in the `Value` column of the server.

**Backend (Predefined report)**

The JasperReport Server sends a value *no matter what default value you have provided in the field*. So if no field is selected (three dashes), you will get `null`. If anything else is selected, you will get that value as a parameter value.

When setting default values those are only being used if no parameter component (input component) will be set in JasperReport Server.

**Conclusion**

The three dashes will never reach the SQL. The parameter will either be `null` or provided with the value you selected in the drop down.

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to interpret both cases, you should change the order of the `OR` and use `IS NULL`, otherwise the first comparison will always be checked (even with `null` values):

```
... AND ($P{paramResource} IS NULL OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),srm_resources.ID) = $P{paramResource}))
```

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful.  So as you see in the code, with the parameter I am using `AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),srm_resources.ID) = $P{paramResource} OR '' = $P{paramResource})` do you by any chance know what I would change the '' to? I tried `is null` but it still came up empty and only works if I put a real value in.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer (or another one) helped you out, consider marking the answer as accepted (see [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)).